# Pandas - wrong week extracted week from date

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract the week from "TIME" column.

- The correct value is 52.
- The value that I get is 1.

Any idea how to fix this?

**Code and results below:**

```
import pandas as pd

#create df
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['TIME','FACILITY'])
df['TIME'] = ['12/30/2019  11:18:29 PM']
df['TIME']=pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])
df['FACILITY'] = ['C201']

#Extract week
df['WW'] = df['TIME'].dt.week
```

[image]

Comment: Why is week number 1 not correct? https://www.calendar-365.com/2019-calendar.html

Comment: Thank you. You are right. 
Still I am interested in a generic solution of the one Maku posted below.

Comment: the correct value is `1` according to [ISO week date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date): `If 31 December is on a Monday or Tuesday it is in week 01 of the next year.`

Comment: @Aprillion Thank you. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what your are looking  for:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['TIME','FACILITY'])
df['TIME'] = ['12/30/2019  11:18:29 PM']
df['TIME']= pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])
df['FACILITY'] = ['C201']

df['WW'] = df['TIME'].dt.strftime("%U")

print(df)
```

Result:

```
                 TIME FACILITY  WW
0 2019-12-30 23:18:29     C201  52
```

Answer (score 3):

As Maku said, unfortunately, it is technically correct. Manual fix if you really want all 2019 dates to be on that "set" of weeks:

```
df['M'] = df.dt.month
df['Y'] = df.dt.year
df['WW'] = df.dt.week
df['WW'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.loc[df.Y == x.Y, 'WW'].max() + 1 if x.WW == 1 and x.month = 12 else x.WW)
```

This basically checks that it's a december date with week = 1 and changes it to a final partial week of its year.

Note: with this, 2019-12-30 is in the 53rd week, since it's the monday after Sunday of week 52.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it is correct even if you apply `dt.weekofyear`

You can instead force it by using lambda:

```
# Note: You can modify the static value '52' and make it more better
df['TIME'].apply(lambda x : 52 if x.year == 2019 else x.week)
```

Comment: I think OP need general solution with multiple datetimes :(

Comment: There should be a method that provides the remaining days of previous year to be added in a certain list to make it applicable in any year but here's my modified solution that only applies to week of year **2019** onwards: `df['TIME'].apply(lambda x : 52 if x.year == 2019 and x.day in [30,31] else x.week)`

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution to the problem is as below, data frame temp is a dataset with timestamp and week of the year

`def weekofmonthc(dt1):
 if (dt1.month == 12) and (dt1.weekofyear == 1):
   mmaxw = temp[(temp['timestamp_utc'].dt.month == dt1.month) & (temp['timestamp_utc'].dt.year == dt1.year)]['timestamp_utc'].dt.weekofyear.max()
   return (mmaxw + 1)
 else:
   return (dt1.weekofyear)`

temp[(temp['timestamp_utc'] > '2014-12-30 23:00:00') & (temp['timestamp_utc'] < '2015-01-01 01:00:00')]['timestamp_utc'].apply(weekofmonthc)