# getting week number from date python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have code as below. My questions:

1. why is it assigning week 1 to `2014-12-29` and `'2014-1-1'`? Why it is not assigning week 53 to `2014-12-29`?
2. how could i assign week number that is continuously increasing? I
   want `'2014-12-29','2015-1-1'` to have week 53 and `'2015-1-15'` to have
   week 55 etc.

```py
x=pd.DataFrame(data=['2014-1-1','2014-12-29','2015-1-1','2015-1-15'],columns=['date'])
```

[image]

```py
x['week_number']=pd.DatetimeIndex(x['date']).week
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas - wrong week extracted week from date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59646787/pandas-wrong-week-extracted-week-from-date)

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600775/how-to-get-week-number-in-python) will answer your first question. Just use different start day as reference.

Comment: As a workaround, you can probably get away with using `x["date"].dt.dayofyear // 7 + 1` (assumes `x["date"]` is a datetime column).

Comment: To answer question 1 more directly: there is no 53rd week. If anything it'd be the 52nd week, but again, see the link in my previous comment for an explanation as to why it's week 1.

Comment: Looks like you're getting an ISO 8601 week number which has some strange, non-intuitive properties.  There's a link to an in depth explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2600878/5987 or you can see a description in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as why the week number is 1 for 12/29/2014 -- see the question I linked to in the comments. For the second part of your question:

January 1, 2014 was a Wednesday. We can take the minimum date of your date column, get the day number and subtract from the difference:

### Solution

```py
# x["date"] = pd.to_datetime(x["date"])  # if not already a datetime column
min_date = x["date"].min() + 1  # + 1 because they're zero-indexed
x["weeks_from_start"] = ((x["date"].diff().dt.days.cumsum() - min_date) // 7 + 1).fillna(1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```py
        date  weeks_from_start
0 2014-01-01                 1
1 2014-12-29                52
2 2015-01-01                52
3 2015-01-15                54
```

### Step by step

The first step is to convert the `date` column to the datetime type, if you haven't already:

```py
In [3]: x.dtypes
Out[3]:
date    object
dtype: object

In [4]: x["date"] = pd.to_datetime(x["date"])

In [5]: x
Out[5]:
        date
0 2014-01-01
1 2014-12-29
2 2015-01-01
3 2015-01-15

In [6]: x.dtypes
Out[6]:
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Next, we need to find the minimum of your date column and set that as the starting date day of the week number (adding 1 because the day number starts at 0):

```py
In [7]: x["date"].min().day + 1
Out[7]: 2
```

Next, use the built-in `.diff()` function to take the differences of adjacent rows:

```py
In [8]: x["date"].diff()
Out[8]:
0        NaT
1   362 days
2     3 days
3    14 days
Name: date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Note that we get `NaT` ("not a time") for the first entry -- that's because the first row has nothing to compare to above it.

The way to interpret these values is that row 1 is 362 days after row 0, and row 2 is 3 days after row 1, etc.

If you take the cumulative sum and subtract the starting day number, you'll get the days since the starting date, in this case `2014-01-01`, as if the Wednesday was day 0 of that first week (this is because when we calculate the number of weeks since that starting date, we need to compensate for the fact that Wednesday was the middle of that week):

```py
In [9]: x["date"].diff().dt.days.cumsum() - min_date
Out[9]:
0      NaN
1    360.0
2    363.0
3    377.0
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Now when we take the floor division by 7, we'll get the correct number of weeks since the starting date:

```py
In [10]: (x["date"].diff().dt.days.cumsum() - 2) // 7 + 1
Out[10]:
0     NaN
1    52.0
2    52.0
3    54.0
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Note that we add 1 because (I assume) you're counting from 1 -- i.e., `2014-01-01` is week 1 for you, and not week 0.

Finally, the `.fillna` is just to take care of that `NaT` (which turned into a `NaN` when we started doing arithmetic). You use `.fillna(value)` to fill `NaN`s with `value`:

```py
In [11]: ((x["date"].diff().dt.days.cumsum() - 2) // 7 + 1).fillna(1)
Out[11]:
0     1.0
1    52.0
2    52.0
3    54.0
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Finally use `.astype()` to convert the column to integers instead of floats.

Comment: why 2015-01-01 has week 53? i want it to be 52 as it falls in the same week as 2014-12-29. Basically I want week1 to start from 30Dec2013 and then continue week number from there

Comment: Okay, see my edit.

Comment: why do we need `cumsum()` and `fillna(1)`?

Comment: See my second edit.